# VirtualBox networking host-only: Linux host XP Guest

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I'm having trouble connecting XP ( Guest system on VBOX ) to Debian Testing (host).

The version VirtualBox 4.1.12

Relevant parts of the output of commands.

#### ifconfig on debian:

```
eth0    
inet addr:192.168.158.5  Bcast:192.168.158.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

vboxnet0  
inet addr:192.168.158.199  Bcast:192.168.158.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

#### ipconfig on XP:

```
IP Address 192.163.158.200 
Subnet mask 255.255.0.0
```

`File->Preferences->Network->edit vboxnet0` yields the following dialogs:

```
Host-Only network Details
 Adaptor:
  Ipv4 Address:192.168.158.199
  Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0


DHCP Server
  Server Address: 192.168.158.198
  Server Mask:255.255.255.0
  Lower Address Bound: 192.168.158.200
  Upper Address Bound:192.168.158.254
```

I cannot ping either machine from the other. Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Why is eth0 and vboxnet0 on the same network ?

Comment: How you are getting the ip address in the host machine i.e. debian whether thru DHCP or u are statically assigning

Comment: The subnet mask is not the same on the XP VM (255.255.0.0 vs. 255.255.255.0). Could easily be the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Your host has two networks of the same ip range (192.168.*.*) so the host routes all communication to its external (eth0) interface. You need to change the vboxnet0 to be a different one (172.16.*.* or something). As long as both do not have the same prefix (192.168) you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have two times the same network on different devices.

To achieve your goal simply use the eth0 network bridge OR build a real bridge with `brctl`, and use that. - Use a different network not used by an external network card.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the Subnet mask in XP maching from 255.255.0.0 to 255.255.255.0